# Django: Improperly configured url: unbalanced parenthesis

Tags: python, django

I'm developing a website ina VM on my Mac which then gets deployed to a remote UAT server.  The VM is set up with the same OS and software stack as the UAT and live servers.  I'm getting the following error when attempting to access the UAT version of my website:

```
"^accounts/update-user-group/(?P<pk>\d" is not a valid regular expression: unbalanced parenthesis
```

On first look it seems pretty obvious what's wrong: The given URL pattern is incomplete. However, my urls.py file has the correct full url:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from django.conf import settings
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url

from views import UserGroupList, UserGroupDetail
from views import UserGroupCreate, UserGroupUpdate, UserGroupDelete
from views import UserDeletedGroups, RecoverDeletedGroup


urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(_(r'^accounts/create-user-group/$'), UserGroupCreate.as_view(), name='user_group_create'),
    url(_(r'^accounts/update-user-group/(?P<pk>\d+)/$'), UserGroupUpdate.as_view(), name='user_group_update'),
    url(_(r'^delete/(?P<pk>\d+)/$'), UserGroupDelete.as_view(), name='user_group_delete'),
    url(_(r'^accounts/user-group-deleted/$'), UserDeletedGroups.as_view(), name='user_group_deleted_list'),
    url(_(r'^recover/(?P<pk>\d+)/$'), RecoverDeletedGroup.as_view(), name='user_group_recover_deleted'),
    url(_(r'^accounts/user-group-details/(?P<pk>\d+)/$'), UserGroupDetail.as_view(), name='user_group_detail'),
    url(_(r'^accounts/user-group-list/$'), UserGroupList.as_view(), name='user_group_list'),
)
```

So the error seems to be getting generated by the second regex in the urlpatterns.  However, If I change the regex to this:

```
url(_(r'^accounts/update-user-group/(?P<pk>[\d]+)/$'), UserGroupUpdate.as_view(), name='user_group_update'),
```

Then the error moves on to the next line.  All I've done here is add square brackets round the `\d`
for the pk argument. How can this simple difference be the cause of the error? And why would it only be happening in my UAT environment and not local development?

Comment: Why are you wrapping your regex strings with ugettext?

Comment: Because its an international site and translatable URLs is one of the requirements.  We've been doing this for a year and it hasn't been causing any problems previously

Comment: It turns out that this wasn't causing a problem due to the fact that we didn't have a translation for that URL in our PO file. Now we do and it is incomplete. Thanks Daniel, your question pointed me in the right direction

Comment: @hellsgate add your solution as an answer and accept it - it might help someone in the future who comes across this

Comment: @TimmyO'Mahony thanks, i need to wait 2 days before I can accept my own anser though

Answer (score 0):

Daniels question pointed me in the right direction for this. The translation for the problem URL in my PO file was incomplete so ensuring that was correct sorted my problem.